# Why pandas profiling isn't showing any output in ipython?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-profiling

I've a quick question about "pandas_profiling" .So basically i'm trying to use the pandas 'profiling' but instead of showing the output it says something like this:

```
<pandas_profiling.ProfileReport at 0x23c02ed77b8>
```

Where i'm making the mistake?? or Does it have anything to do with Ipython?? Because i'm using Ipython in Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
pfr = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
pfr.to_notebook_iframe()
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas_profiling creates an object that then needs to be displayed or output. One standard way of doing so is to save it as an HTML:

`profile.to_file(outputfile="sample_file_name.html")`

("profile" being the variable you used to save the profile itself)

It doesn't have to do with ipython specifically - the difference is that because you're going line by line (instead of running a full block of code, including the reporting step) it's showing you the object itself. The code above should allow you to see the report once you open it up.